# Word 2010 add-in targeting .net 4.5 framework?

Tags: ms-word, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5

I am upgrading to VS 2012 with an existing word 2010 add-in project.

When I try to change the project to compile for .net 4.5 I get the following error:
"The .NET Framework version you selected is not supported by this project type."

Is there a new vs 2010 add-in template that will work with .net 4.5?  Is this scenario not supported?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Word 2010 add-ins only support .net 4.0.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/vsto/thread/14a645f3-4ecd-4815-9fdd-eb2756b70945